# what's wrong with this c function?

Tags: c

The following function has to split a line in 2 or more lines each of which is shorter than s.

```
char **splitline(FILE *fp, int s)
{
    char **l;
    char c;
    int ccounter;
    int lcounter;

    c = fgetc(fp);
    if (c == EOF)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    lcounter=0;
    l = malloc(sizeof(char **));
    l[lcounter] = malloc((SIZE+2)*sizeof(char));

    ccounter = 0;
    while (c != EOF && c != '\n')
    {
        l[lcounter][ccounter] = c;
        ccounter++;
        c = fgetc(fp);

        if (ccounter == SIZE)
        {
            l[lcounter][ccounter] = '\n';
            ccounter++;
            l[lcounter][ccounter] = '\0';

            realloc(l, (lcounter+2) * sizeof(char **));

            lcounter++;

            l[lcounter] = malloc((SIZE+2) * sizeof(char));
            ccounter = 0;
        }
    }

    if (ccounter == 0)
    {
        l[lcounter][ccounter] = '\0'; 
    }
    else
    {
        l[lcounter][ccounter] = '\n';
        ccounter++;
        l[lcounter][ccounter] = '\0';

        realloc(l, (lcounter+2) * sizeof(char **));

        lcounter++;

        ccounter = 0;
        l[lcounter] = malloc((SIZE+2) * sizeof(char));
        l[lcounter][ccounter] = '\0';
    }

    return l;
}
```

Comment: and when you're done with that, indent your code (properly) :P

Comment: Comments would be nice too. I always write the comments first and fill in the code afterwards.

Comment: Note that sizeof (char) is never necessary (the value is always 1), and might be considered as clutter. This is of course subjective, I just want to point it out.

Comment: Is this question asking for a review, or could you explain what you're getting from it vs what you think you should be getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main one I can spot: realloc may not keep your buffer at the same address. You should use

```
 l = realloc(...)
```

Actually, see the comment of Matteo below. Realloc may do one of three things:

- extend the size of the buffer you already have (in which case you'll get the same pointer back);
- allocate a new buffer elsewhere, copy your buffer's contents across and free the original (in which case you'll get a different pointer back);
- find itself unable to get you a buffer of the required size anywhere and fail, leaving your current contents intact (returning NULL).

In the final case, assignment without checking the return value would cause a memory leak.

Comment: no, you should first assign the returned value to a temporary pointer, check for `NULL` and then assign. This because if `realloc` fails you get `NULL` and the original allocated memory is left untouched (thus you still have to deallocate it). But if you already assigned the `NULL` to the pointer, you've already lost any reference to the old allocated memory, and you can't free it anymore.

Comment: +1 - you're quite right. I've adjusted my answer, hopefully to be more accurate.

Answer (score 5):

- You are using an undefined constant SIZE instead of the argument `s` to your function to control the maximum lengths of your lines.  Since `s` is a signed integer, you should check it for sanity (it should be positive (non-zero) number, maybe not larger than 1 MiB; maybe you want to set a bigger lower limit than 1; maybe you default to 80 if the caller screws up, or maybe you return with an error).
- You are using `char c;` to save the value read with `fgetc()`; sadly, that means your EOF test is unreliable.  Either you'll stop prematurely when someone supplies 'ÿ' (y-umlaut, hex 0xFF in ISO 8859-1, 8859-15, or U+00FF in ISO 10646 - Unicode) or you won't stop at all, depending on whether the type `char` is signed or unsigned.  Always remember: `getchar()` and relatives return an `int`!
- A variable `l` is inviting confusion with the constant `1`; generally avoid it.
- Your main loop condition would be better if you tested the result of `fgetc()` directly.

  ```
  int c;
  while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && c != '\n')
  {
      ...
  }
  ```

  As it is, you read a character part way through the loop and don't check it properly.  You might then use `ungetc()` to push the character first read back into the input stream; it makes the input processing more uniform.  Alternatively, you might set things up so that everything works correctly if the first call to `fgetc()` is in the loop control *and* it returns EOF.
- As [Tommy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/427332/tommy) pointed out, you must capture the output of `realloc()`; there is no guarantee that it will return its input pointer as the result.  You should also learn now that you do not save the result of `realloc()` into the variable specified as its first argument.  You immediately leak memory if you do and the reallocation fails (because you've lost the pointer to the old memory - it just got zeroed).  So, to be safe, you use:

  ```
  char **new_array = realloc(l, (lcounter+1) * sizeof(*new_array));
  if (new_array == 0)
      ...handle out of memory...
  else
      l = new_array;
  ```

  A couple of points here.  You allocated `(lcounter+2)` values, but I think you only ever use one of them (unless there's a terminal null pointer to mark the end of the array).  You specified `sizeof(char **)` but actually you want an array of `char *` values.  Fortunately, all (object) pointers are the same size - the C standard guarantees that; only POSIX guarantees that function pointers are the same size as object pointers (the C standard does not).  So, `sizeof(char **) == sizeof(char *)` and you are safe, but you are not asking for what you wanted.
- A corollary to the discussion about `realloc()` possibly failing is `malloc()` may fail too.  You should error check your memory allocation - or use a set of cover functions for the standard library that only return if the pointer that is returned is not null.  If you don't check it, your program will crash eventually because of a memory allocation failure - even on a machine with 24 GiB of main memory (though it might take a while to get to that point).
- There is a lot of repetition in the code.  You should look to avoid that.  It means using a sub-function, perhaps, to manage the memory allocations.

If you fix those, you're in with a fighting chance of getting a working function.  You should also write the code to release the allocated memory that you return, so that the users doesn't have to devise a method to do so on your behalf.  Always worry about who is going to release allocated memory and how it will be released.

---

[Chris Lutz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60777/chris-lutz) asked:

> And where does the standard guarantee that all object pointer types are the same size?

I believe the relevant section of the (C99 - ISO/IEC 9899:1999) standard is:

> §6.3.2.3 Pointers
>
> 1 A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any incomplete or object
>   type. A pointer to any incomplete or object type may be converted to a pointer to void
>   and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

That basically says all object pointer types can be converted to void pointers and back again without loss of information, which means that they must all be the same size.  Note that the category 'object pointers' does not include 'function pointers'.

The relevant section of the [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_12) standard (about function pointers) is §2.12.3 (at the bottom of the linked section).

Comment: Don't check for sanity, start with sanity. `size_t` for life.

Comment: And where does the standard guarantee that all object pointer types are the same size?

Comment: "Convert to and from `void *`" doesn't mean "same size as `void *`. I can convert any signed integer values to and from `intmax_t` but that doesn't mean that all signed integer types have the same size. An `int *` could be 2 bytes and `void *` 4, and converting `int *` to `void *` and back would still give you the same 2 bytes. No problem with the standard.

Comment: thanks for highlighting all these mistakes , actually what caused my function not to work was the misuse of realloc()

Comment: @user591931: fair enough - that was the biggest issue, certainly; the rest were more nearly cosmetic.  Select Tommy's answer as the most relevant; he got there first on the realloc issue.